# SQL Alchemy Cannot Open Database File when run as agent

Tags: python, sqlite, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, launchd

I've written a program that connects to a local db.sqlite3 file and it has worked fine when I run the command in the debugger or in terminal.  However, I recently tried to automate this by using Launch Control to create a launch agent in OS X.  When I do that, it fails on the below with the following error message:

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///db.sqlite3', connect_args={'check_same_thread':False})

error:
    sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) unable to open database file None None
```

I thought this was maybe the file permissions, so I changed that to 'Read/write' for everyone, but still no dice.  Here is how I am calling the program in Launch Control/lauchd.  Any pointers on this one would be a huge help as I have other scripts that I want to run that use sqlite too.  Thanks!

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>local.brianharnett1.infringe</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/bin/python3</string>
        <string>/Users/brianharnett1/Documents/Infringer/infringe.py</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/local.brianharnett1.infringe.err</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/local.brianharnett1.infringe.out</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this out.  Launch Control and Launchd has a working directory argument.  Populating that with the directory of my python project did the trick!